# Checking if all the characters from an A-Z is present in the string

Tags: java, performance, strings, comparative-review

> A string is said to be complete if it contains all the characters from
>   a to z. Given a string, check if it complete or not.
>
> `Input` First line of the input contains the number of strings N. It is
>   followed by N lines each contains a single string.
>
> `Output` For each test case print "YES" if the string is complete, else
>   print "NO"
>
> Constraints `1 <= N <= 10` The length of the string is at max 100 and
>   the string contains only the characters a to z.

Here are the two solutions that I wrote:

```
class TestClass {
    private static byte N;
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
       N = Byte.parseByte(keyboard.readLine());
        for (byte i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String testingString = keyboard.readLine();
            isCompleteString(testingString);
        }
    }

    private static void isCompleteString(String testingString) {
        String resultString= "";
        char[] toChar = testingString.toCharArray();
        int length = toChar.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(resultString.indexOf(toChar[i])==-1){
                resultString=resultString.concat(toChar[i]+"");

            }


        }

        if(resultString.length()==26)System.out.println("YES");
        else System.out.println("NO");
    }

}
```

This took 1.6469 secs against various inputs, while this code took:

```
class TestClass {
    private static byte N;
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
       N = Byte.parseByte(keyboard.readLine());
        for (byte i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String testingString = keyboard.readLine();
            isCompleteString(testingString);
        }
    }

    private static void isCompleteString(String testingString) {

        char[] toChar = testingString.toCharArray();
        int length = toChar.length;
        boolean[] findingAlphabet = new boolean[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            byte alphabets = (byte) toChar[i];
            findingAlphabet[122-alphabets]=true;

        }
        int count=0;
        for(boolean b:findingAlphabet){
            if(b)
            count++;
        }
        if(count==26)System.out.println("YES");
        else System.out.println("NO");
    }

}
```

1.5818 secs against various inputs.

How can I optimize these programs further (I have used `BitSet`)? What are other possible optimized methods of doing the same?

Comment: See: [Pangram (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram)

Comment: May I ask what kind of machine you are using? Your 1st program took 0.15 seconds and your second program took 0.14 seconds on my machine, using an input of 10 strings, 80 characters per string. But when I removed everything but the input parsing, the program took 0.12 seconds.  So really your functions are running in < 0.03 seconds.  I like your second version better, but the problem set is so small that nothing is going to make it that much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static byte N;
```

We know that `N<=100`, but this is a very premature optimization. In theory, you're saving 3 bytes *total*. Actually, it'll get rounded up to a nearest multiple of 8 or whatever and you save nothing at all.

It's also no good idea top make everything `static`.

```
BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
```

But the input does not come from the keyboard. Or can you type 100 lines in two seconds? I'd call it `in` as I'm lazy, something like `reader` would be fine.

```
isCompleteString(testingString);
```

According to the name, `isCompleteString` returns `boolean`. And there should be a method doing just this. Coupling output with computation makes you method 100% non-reusable.

#### First version

```
    String resultString= "";
```

Switch on your warning to see unused variables.

```
    char[] toChar = testingString.toCharArray();
    int length = toChar.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

This looks like a premature optimization. And `toChar` is a bad name as there's no `char` but `char[]`. The IDE proposes `charArrays` or `chars`, which is both better.

If you want to use a `char[]`, then use simply

```
   for (char c : chars)
```

This is clearly non-optimal

```
        if(resultString.indexOf(toChar[i])==-1){
            resultString=resultString.concat(toChar[i]+"");
        }
```

for many reasons

- `indexOf` - you're running through the string for each char
- `toChar[i]+""` creates a `String` from each `char` needlessly
- `resultString.concat(...)` creates a new `String` every time

You could use a `StringBuilder` here.

But creating a `String` only to measure it's length is plain wrong. You could count the `char`s instead.

But counting the chars is plain wrong too. If you want to know if a beer crate is full, do you count the bottles? Or do you if there's a bottle missing?

[image: beer crate]

```
    if(resultString.length()==26)System.out.println("YES");
    else System.out.println("NO");
```

This should be written as

```
   System.out.println(resultString.length()==26 ? "YES" : "NO");
```

apart from that 1. there should be no `resultString`, 2. there should be a method computing and a method printing.

#### Second version

```
    boolean[] findingAlphabet = new boolean[26];
```

No good name. What about `foundChars` or simply `found`?

```
        byte alphabets = (byte) toChar[i];
```

What byte? Never use a `byte`, unless either it's exactly what's needed or you have a big bunch of them.

```
        findingAlphabet[122-alphabets]=true;
```

Nice obfuscation. What about

```
       found[chars[i] - 'a'] = true;
```

? And bottle counting again

```
    int count=0;
    for(boolean b:findingAlphabet){
        if(b)
        count++;
    }
```

This should be

```
    for (boolean b : found) {
        if (!b) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

> How can I optimaize these programs further (I have used BitSet)?

You haven't. But `BitSet` is slower than a `boolean[]` (except when memory locality comes in play).

It looks like most of the time gets spend on IO. Not surprising, even the first solution with doing 26 times `indexOf` on a 100 chars string is not computationally intensive.

It could be sped up by avoiding strings and working with the input bytes directly. But I'd concentrate on readability first, otherwise it'll become a huge mess.

You may want to specify input encoding as US-ASCII as it's sufficient and much faster than UTF-8 which may be your platform default.

Comment: Thanks for so clearly mentioning so many things .. Will take care of names in future .. :)

Answer (score 4):

### Declarations

The class should be public.  The `isCompleteString()` function should probably be public as well, since it implements the primary functionality of the program.

`String args[]` is allowable.  However, `String[] args` is considered more idiomatic in Java, and easier to read.  (You wrote `char[] toChar` further down, which is good.)

Declaring `throws Exception` is a bit sloppy and mysterious.  If you only need `IOException`, then declare `throws IOException`.

`isCompleteString()` prints its output rather than returning a boolean.  It is a strong convention in Java that methods named `isSomething()`, `hasSomething()`, or `canSomething()` should return a boolean.  Also, printing the output prevents you from writing unit tests or reusing the code.

### `main()`

`N` should not be a static variable.  It's just a loop counter within `main()`, and should therefore just be a local variable.

Using `byte` for `N` is weird.  Why limit yourself to 127 test cases?  Just use `int`, which is more natural, more scalable, and no less efficient.

`java.util.Scanner` offers a slightly nicer interface for reading lines from `System.in`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        for (int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); n > 0; n--) {
            boolean complete = isCompleteString(scanner.nextLine());
            System.out.println(complete ? "YES" : "NO");
        }
    }
}
```

### `isCompleteString()`

As you noticed, the second implementation is more efficient.  Searching a string is less efficient than arithmetic and an array lookup.  Concatenating a string is less efficient than setting one element of an array.

`122-alphabets` is weird and mysterious.  `alphabets - 'a'` would work just as well, and the intention would be more obvious.

Your second implementation is not really using `java.util.BitSet`, but it does something similar in spirit.  Note that you only need a set of 26 bits.  Guess what?  An `int` has 32 bits!  The following solution should be even faster.

```
/**
 * Tests whether all characters 'a' to 'z' are present in a string.
 * Behavior is undefined if the string contains any character outside
 * the 'a'-'z' range.
 */
public static boolean isCompleteString(String string) {
    int seen = 0;
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
        // 'a'=1, 'b'=2, 'c'=4, ..., 'z'=2^25
        seen |= 1 << (c - 'a');
    }
    // Are the 26 least-siginificant bits all set?
    return seen == (1 << 26) - 1;
}
```

Comment: The last function you posted .. it was just like i learned a new things .. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

1. **Method name/return type**

   ```
   private static void isCompleteString(String testingString)
   ```

   Usually, the `is` prefix is reserved for methods that return a `boolean` value, so that your caller code becomes:

   ```
   System.out.println(isCompleteString(testingString) ? "YES" : "NO");
   ```

   To nitpick, the purpose of this method is also not to find a "complete" `String`, but rather determine if it contains all letters of the English i.e. "US-ASCII" alphabet. A better name might be [`isPangram`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) or `containsEveryLetter`.
2. **Testing/timings**

   As pointed out by [@maaartinus](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/91894/27975)'s excellent answer, how are you getting the < 2 seconds for "various inputs"? What's your test size, and have you performed multiple runs to take an average of your test timings? Are you only testing your main method, or the time it takes for the JVM to start up, get ready to receive the user input from `System.in`, and then handle the output to `System.out`?

   This is where unit testing comes into play. Again, as mentioned in his answer, this is not a performance-intensive problem to begin with, so I'm not too sure as to why you have tagged it with [performance](/questions/tagged/performance).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to count the already found chars. Something like below. Saves you the last loop and also processing of the rest of the string once all chars are found.

```
int distinctCharsCnt =0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{ 
    byte alphabets = (byte) toChar[i]; 
    int charIndex = 122-alphabets;
    if(!findingAlphabet[charIndex])
    {
         findingAlphaber[charIndex] = true;
         distinctCharsCnt++;
    }
    if(distinctCharsCnt == 26)
    { return true; }
}
```